# Cannot connect to Azure Files share

Tags: entra-id, azure-storage

I have set up an Azure Files share with Azure AD Kerberos as the authentication source.

I get the error below when running the connection script (Active Directory authentication) on an end user's PC.

The PC is Azure AD-joined, with the user logging in with an Azure AD account.

Users need to be able to access the Azure Files share when they are not on the local domain.

> New-PSDrive : The system cannot contact a domain controller to service
> the authentication request. Please try again     later
> At C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\connect-files-share.ps1:4 char:5  +
> New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\storage ...  +
>
> ```
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
> ```

The Azure website states: "Azure AD Kerberos authentication allows users to connect to Azure Files over the internet without requiring a line-of-sight to domain controllers."

[image: Azure AD Kerberos Source]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article resolved the issue (creating the registry key):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-azure-active-directory-enable?tabs=azure-portal#configure-the-clients-to-retrieve-kerberos-tickets